# Add click events to php generated elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a page that will generate a table of divs. Each row has a cell with a link. When that link is clicked a hidden div between the current row and the next will toggleSlide out.

The link will have id="clickLink_10" and the hidden div will have id="10" and class="hiddenDiv". The number 10 is a dynamic number generated form the id of the post in the database.

I have the animation working fine, as long as I hard code the numbers. But I want to connect the link to it's hidden div dynamically, since the rows will be fetched from a database.

Here's an example of how the **html** may look (it's more complicated in reality, but this is the key part):

```
<div><a href="#" id="clickLink_11">CLICK HERE</a></div>
<div class="hiddenDiv" id="11">blabla</div>

<div><a href="#" id="clickLink_1">CLICK HERE</a></div>
<div class="hiddenDiv" id="1">blabla</div>

<div><a href="#" id="clickLink_3">CLICK HERE</a></div>
<div class="hiddenDiv" id="3">blabla</div>
```

**And here's what I'm trying to do in jQuery:**

```
hiddenDivs = $('.hiddenDiv');

for(var i = 0; i < hiddenDivs.length; i++ ) {
   $("#clickLink_" + hiddenDivs[i].id).click( function() { 
      $(hiddenDivs[i]).slideToggle(1000);
   });
}
```

Which won't work obviously.I know I'm treating the i-variable wrong so view this a s dummy code. Very grateful for any help.

Comment: do you plan on closing out the `div`s with  `class="hiddenDiv"`?

Comment: @manta Forgot to put it in the example code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid option could be using `data-` attributes. I'll also change your numeric ids as only numbers is not a valid html id.

**HTML**

```
<div><a href="#" class="clickLink" data-hidden-id="11">CLICK HERE</a></div>
<div class="hiddenDiv" id="hidden_11">

<div><a href="#" class="clickLink" data-hidden-id="1">CLICK HERE</a></div>
<div class="hiddenDiv" id="hidden_1">

<div><a href="#" class="clickLink" data-hidden-id="3">CLICK HERE</a></div>
<div class="hiddenDiv" id="hidden_3">
```

**JS**

```
$(".clickLink").click( function() { 
   var hiddenDivId = "hidden_" + $(this).data("hidden-id");
   $("#" + hiddenDivId ).slideToggle(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `^=` operator with an attribute selector to select elements. the `^=` operator tells it to look for the attribute that "starts with" something, so:

```
$("a[id^=comment_]").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var hideId = $(this).attr("id").replace("comment_","");
   $("#"+hideId).slideToggle(1000);
});
```

So the selector `a[id^=comment_]` is basically saying select all anchor tags that have an id that start with `comment_`